# Pdf modification on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, frameworks

I am looking to be able to open a pdf file (done) and then be able to use the touch screen to sign the pdf and then save it with the modification. From what i have read this is no easy task, and i have no idea where to begin. Any of you know any tutorials or frameworks that will help me with this ?

Also if possible being able to modify fields of a pdf file, on the desktop the pdf can have fields you can click on then type in to fill out the form, without the need to ever print. If this is possible as well that would be perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe libHaru (http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page) does what you want, it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not support modifying PDF files, only creating them.

Comment: @LOST were you able to achieve this. I have tried libharu but it only creates a new pdf whereas I want to embed annotations into an existing pdf. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Does your starting point have to be a PDF?  steipete's suggestion of using a system to create the PDF would work if your app workflow could create the PDF (sans signature) and display it, the user "signs" it in your app, and you create the PDF again this time with the signature embedded.  It depends on whether this flow is an option for your app.  Often it seems easier if you treat PDF as a final document and produce the PDF in it's final form each time (final meaning that you're not going to try modifying it).